# Including Django REST Framework urls returns 404

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I get a 404 showing the following url patterns when I try to browse to `http://localhost:8000/api/v1/api-dev/`:

```
^api/v1/ ^api-dev/ ^login/$ [name='login']
^api/v1/ ^api-dev/ ^logout/$ [name='logout']
```

What's up with the whitespace and ^?

Here's the relevant code from the app.urls:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url, include
urlpatterns = patterns('',

    url(r'^api/v1/', include('api.urls')),

)
```

And from the api.urls:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url, include
from rest_framework import routers
from api.views import views


urlpatterns = patterns('',

    url(r'^api-dev/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),

)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, the answer is just that I'm an idiot... there is no

```
http://localhost:8000/api/v1/api-dev/
```

Only `http://localhost:8000/api/v1/api-dev/login`

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the url part from both:

```
(r'^api/v1/', include('api.urls')),
(r'^api-dev/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
```

Comment: try adding a $ at the end of /api-dev/ like /api-dev/$